# Saving packet.data() to String with ASyncUDP on ESP32

Tags: arduino, esp32

I have basically taken the [AsyncUDP Server example](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/libraries/AsyncUDP/examples/AsyncUDPServer/AsyncUDPServer.ino) and I am trying to save the content of `packet.data()` into a string. I have gotten all sorts of errors about `invalid conversion`. I have been struggling with this for hours and have not recorded every step.

If I use `String testString = packet.data();` I get `invalid conversion from 'uint8_t* {aka unsigned char*}' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive]`.

I am not strong enough at C apparently to fully understand all of these data types, pointers, etc. and how to get my way out of what seems like a simple problem.

Answer (score 2):

Save version:

```
char* tmpStr = (char*) malloc(packet.length() + 1);
memcpy(tmpStr, packet.data(), packet.length());
tmpStr[packet.length()] = '\0'; // ensure null termination
String testString = String(tmpStr);
free(tmpStr); // Strign(char*) creates a copy so we can delete our one
```

The following should work **if** the data of the packet is null terminated:

```
String testString = String( (char*) packet.data());
```

This is possible, because a *unit8_t* * is enssentially the same as a *char* * but the compiler can not do this conversion by itselfe so you have to do an explicit cast.
Then the constructor of *String(char*)* can be used.

Comment: The problem has shifted a little bit so I haven't tried this exact solution but I did use a portion of it. Thank you!